phpGrid-Add a variable to Virtual column (not calculated field)
I have read the phpGrid documentation and tested several other scripts but I cannot get a virtual column populated with just test or a static variable.
I looked at Add static column in phpgrid manually which has an accepted answer but it doesn't work and causes a 500 error (no error codes or reasons were displayed).


$col_formatter = <<<COLFORMATTER
function(cellvalue, options, rowObject){    
    return "ABC";
}
COLFORMATTER;

$dg -> add_column(
        'XYZ', 
        array('name'=>'XYZ', 
            'index'=>'XYZ', 
            'width'=>'360', 
            'align'=>'left', 
            'sortable'=>false,
            'formatter'=>$col_formatter),
        'XYZ');



When I remove that code the page loads as expected. All I want to do for the end result is to have a virtual column appear using a $variable I set.
